# Will CodeCache in JVM be flushed if -XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing is not used?

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments, java-opts

I was monitoring the javaDB(derby) using jconsole, my java version is 1.6.0_27.

As I read in this article, [CodeCache is full. Compiler has been disabled](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2012/05/codecache-is-full-compiler-has-been-disabled/):

- I thought the CodeCache will not be flushed without **-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing**
- **-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing** is not automatically turned on until 1.7.0_4.

But the jconsole shows the CodeCache usage falls down, which surprised me:

[image: CodeCache Usage Falls Down]

Is there any explanation for this?  What is in CodeCache besides the JIT compiled method?

Comment: Could be due to some methods being uncompiled.

Comment: Thanks assylias, do you mean some methods need to be discard because of 'over optimized' or something? I read from a JVM article that sometime JVM optimized methods based on statistical information, which may cut out some logical branch that rarely happen.

Comment: There is that or for example methods that need to be decompiled in case of polymorphism - see for example: http://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/invoke-interface-optimisations.html. Whether that is the reason for what you observe I don't know - it's only a guess.

Answer (score 1):

The reason maybe is still the option:UseCodeCacheFlushing=true.
The default config of 3 version JDK below:

```
$ java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep CodeCacheFlush
 bool UseCodeCacheFlushing                      = true                                {product}
```

java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

```
$ ./java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep CodeCacheFlush
uintx CodeCacheFlushingMinimumFreeSpace         = 1536000         {product}
 intx MinCodeCacheFlushingInterval              = 30              {product}
 bool UseCodeCacheFlushing                      = true            {product}
```

java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)

```
$ java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep CodeCacheFlush
uintx CodeCacheFlushingMinimumFreeSpace         = 1536000         {product}           
 intx MinCodeCacheFlushingInterval              = 30              {product}           
 bool UseCodeCacheFlushing                      = true            {product}
```

java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)